# Showing that if $\chi(G) = n$ then $G$ must be $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory

How should I go about trying to proof that if $\chi(G) = n$ then $G$ must be $K_n$? Hints anyone?

Comment: I assume "X" was intended to be $\chi$?

Comment: yes it is thanks

Comment: And you need the assumption that the number of vertices in $G$ is $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there is no edge between vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G$.  Can you color them the same color?  What does that make $\chi(G)$?